# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer absent

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In most demos I have seen
1) WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (For configuration)

2)AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer (For initialising the SECURITY FILTERS )

In my project at  work we are also  using SPRING SECURITY,but i couldn't any of the above mentioned classes.

So how in my project we are initializing Spring Security filters and configuring it?

In my project we are implementing/extending the following interfaces/classes

My application uses SPRING BOOT

a) AuthenticationProvider

b) Authentication

c) Filter

Answer (score 1):

> So how in my project we are initializing Spring Security filters and
>   configuring it?

They are defined by the spring boot 's auto configuration. The overall workflow is:

1. If you do not `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` bean , [SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/36c1c051b8106371d37f8a747cea0e369a8e5c84/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.java#L40) will create one for you.
2. [WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/17aaf26590aadfc24b58be72a985ddbbe1611742/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration.java#L28) will make sure `@EnableWebSecurity` is always present.
3. `@EnableWebSecurity` will import the spring security default configuration (`WebSecurityConfiguration`) which define the famous [springSecurityFilterChain](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/047bd16b5156de0bb595ff6b324a63cef92b1fe1/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.java#L96) bean.
4. [SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/36c1c051b8106371d37f8a747cea0e369a8e5c84/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.java#L64) will register `springSecurityFilterChain` to the embeddable server. (Through by defining a `FilterRegistrationBean` (see [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-add-a-servlet-filter-or-listener-as-spring-bean))). This is equivalent to what `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` does but in the spring-boot embeddable server way.

Comment: Thanks a lot .It clears my doubt .But I have one last question when should we explicity use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  and AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer  and when we shouldn't.And doest it make any difference?

Comment: They do the different things. You always need `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` or other sort of the mechanism , which is equivalent to register springSecurityFilterChain  as `<filter>` in `web.xml` .`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is for customising the spring security setting. You need to configure it if you do not like the default settings.